# Diablo III Play On Linux

Tags: 12.04, wine, games, opengl, playonlinux

I'm using the PlayOnLinux program to install Diablo III on my Ubuntu 12.04 OS. I get to a point where it says

```
Please wait while vcrun2008 sp1 x86 is installed...
```

It then stays at this point forever.

Do I need to install it a different way?

On a side note, when I start PlayOnLinux it gives me an error box that says:

> PlayOnLinux is unable to find 32bits OpenGL libraries - You might
>   encounter problem with your games

and also a separate error from Wine

> PlayOnLinux cannot find wine

I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it or if this is a separate issue.

I used the following commands to install PlayOnLinux:

> ```
> wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
> sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install playonlinux
> ```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

And that should install wine properly for you. Try again.

Comment: This worked great, I was able to get through the rest of the install and bring open the game. It seems to run very sluggish though. Not sure if it has to do with video drivers, or if I should run the game another way though...

Comment: The latest version of Diablo III appears to need Win XP SP2, but wine says it is SP 1.  Do you know how to work around this?

Comment: Sorry, no I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

*2yearslater* This still happens. I had the exact same problem. I tried the above answer and I think it helped.

But make sure to uninstall PlayOnLinux, then install Wine properly^ as above, then re-install PlayOnLinux.

After this, in my case, it prompted that the virtual drive already existed (from previous attempts). Because I chose "Overwrite", it didn't work the first times.

It worked after deleting the existing virtual drive and re-creating it.